# how to force all new users to only become a "customer" role in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

**(first of all excuse me for my bad English writing)**

in last 2 days my WordPress website have a problem.
when every one sign up on my website become an admin !!!
I try all possible solutions but not work.

**I need a hook to force all new registered users to only have a "customer" role. or immediately auto change there role to customer from admin after signup**

I use DIGITS plugin for signup form (OTP plugin)

I use this code but not working:

```
function my_func1($user_id){
    $wp_user_object = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
    $wp_user_object->set_role('customer');
}
add_action('user_register','my_func1');
```

Comment: While it is possible to override the user role with a hook, you're patching over the problem. It would be advisable to figure out why new signups are being assigned the admin role in the first place. What's your "New User Default Role"? You'll find that in Settings -> General.

Comment: Default role set to customer but not working

Answer (score 0):

go to Dashboard>setting>new user role> set it to customer or Subscriber.
If this doesn't help then you can install Ultimate member plugin and force all users to customer roles

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 11, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    $current_user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $current_user->remove_role('administrator');
    $current_user->add_role('customer');
}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: not working....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).